# Some questions about Valve's Steam Web API - Fetching Dota 2 Match History

Tags: data-science, steam, steam-web-api

I wanted to write a little program to analyse the Dota 2 matches in order to program a Hero Picking Tool. If there will be some machine learning, is still up to decide for me

I just checked out the Steam Web API documentation and wrote a little program to get Data and write it in a file, but I have an issue with the commands GetMatchHistoryBySequenceNum and GetMatchHistory, so I have two questions about that.

1. I used the this "command" to get a list of games:
   https‍://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_205790/GetMatchHistoryBySequenceNum/v1/?key=..my key

   What does IDOTA2Match_205790 mean? There is also a version of this command, using IDOTA2Match_570, where I get different results. What does IDOTA2Match_ID do? I never found anything about this.
2. Somehow, the parameter start_at_match_seq_num does not work. I always get the same results. I know I need the sequence id instead of the match id, but the sequence id is a number in between 0 and 100 when using GetMatchHistoryBySequenceNum.
3. Additional information:

   I want to use GetMatchHistoryBySequenceNum instead of GetMatchHistory because GetMatchHistory shows weird behaviour: It returns you the latest finished games, ordered by the **starting time**, not the finishing time. This is extremely unsuited, because it returns you many games with game length under 10 minutes, and rarely games over 30 minutes.

   (For Dota players) I think (I have the suspicion) that this is also the reason why websites like dotapicker.com seem to favor undying and other early game heroes.

My code is here:

```
for($pages = 0 ; $pages<3; $pages++){

    for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++){

        if(strpos($homepage, "match_id", $offset+10)==false){   
            break;
        }

        $match_id_str = "";
        $index1  = strpos($homepage, "match_id", $offset+10);
        $offset = $index1;

        #10 to 16: this is the letters after the search-word "match_id"  (the actual number)
        for ($x = 10; $x <= 16; $x++) {
            $match_id_str = $match_id_str.$homepage[$index1+$x];
        }

    }

    $cmd_url  = "https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_205790/GetMatchHistoryBySequenceNum/v1/?key=My_key&start_at_match_seq_num=".match_id_str;
    $homepage = file_get_contents($cmd_url);
    file_put_contents($file, $homepage, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

I know this is kind of a niche topic, but this is also the reason why it is so hard to find information about it.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but I will answer in case anyone else sees this post.

**First Part**

From https://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=58317:

> If you are developing your actual dynamic API calls, (first make sure
>   you have implemented a suitable request limit as above) consider using
>   the Dota2 Beta TEST API, which works identically to the Dota2 Beta
>   API, except its urls are different:

```
Replace "IDOTA2Match_570" with "IDOTA2Match_205790"
```

**Second Part**

`start_at_match_seq_num` requires the actual sequence ID of the match.
You can use the `GetMatchDetails` endpoint to get the sequence number of a particular match.

https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetMatchDetails

The sequence number will be listed in the response object as `match_seq_num`.

Answer (score 0):

I get the `570` from `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2`

```
...
{"appid":570,"name":"Dota 2"}
...
{"appid":205790,"name":"Dota 2 Test"}
```

So I think the  is the game's appid.